# How to track logout details when browser is closed explicitly without Logout using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make a Login details of my users.

I am storing the following columns in a database table:

```
IPAddress, LoginTime, LogOutTime, LoginPlace
```

I can successfully get the details when user logs in and logs out manually (by clicking on `Logout` button)

My problem is when user does not click `Logout` or session expired or directly close the browser, then I am unable to track the record.

I am thinking to add code in the `Session_End` event in `Global.asax` file to track. But how could I track the session?

Is it a good solution?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting some kind of helper method inside any controller/action called for example UpdateLastVisited?

UpdateLastVisited would look like.

```
            UpdateLastVisited(this.User)
                {  
                       "UPDATE [dbo].[User] set LastVisited = @date WHERE Id = @userId";
                        AddParameters etc..
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you should be keeping in mind while saving IPAddress of the user:

1. If you are developing this site for intranet and the users have machines which have IP Addresses dynamically assigned, your logic is bound to go wrong.
2. If you are developing site for Internet, the IP address that you get is that of ISP. To get around this you will have to use some sort of ActiveX (Not suggested).
3. If you still decide to go ahead with 2 remember you will fallback on 1 and hence 4 is the better option to go forward with.
4. Either don't code for web applications having dependencies on IP Address or ensure you are writing this application for Intranet and have static IP Addresses allocated to the machines.

Having said this, coming onto your actual problem of Logging out the user when the browser is closed without logging out:

1. Write a HTTP based web service which is part of your Web Application. Expose a web method say "Logout" and call this method using AJAX on Window.Close() event of javascript.
2. Incase you don't want to move forward with WebService, you could call your logout webpage from with in javascript on Window.close().
3. Even though you use one of above two approaches remember to have session time out on in your server side code.
   I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> **But how could I track the session?**

An ASP.NET [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is clearly defined as an object that is attached to a specific user:

> ASP.NET session state identifies requests from the same browser during a limited time window as a session, and provides a way to persist variable values for the duration of that session.

so, by definition, when you access `Session` it's going to be attached to a user and ASP.NET is going to keep that in sync for you. Now, leveraging that information, I would recommend that you store what you can during `Session_Start`:

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;

    session["IPAddress"] = Request.UserHostAddress;
    session["LoginTime"] = DateTime.Now;

    // you'll need to plug in here how you're going to determine this
    session["LoginPlace"] = "something";
}
```

and then in the `Session_End` you can do this:

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["LogOutTime"] = DateTime.Now;

    // and now here you can persist those values to the database because
    // the session has ended
}
```

and then I'm going to recommend that you do something a little different during logout. Rather than setting those values and persisting them to the database, like you say you are now, do this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
```

that will force the `Session_End` to raise and this will give your code some consistency. Further, it cleans up the session on the server immediately. See, when a user "logs out", unless you've actually killed their session, it's still alive on the server until it times out.